# Command line service for deploying Docker containers to my servers

Tags: docker

I recently created a simple Node.JS app and the container/image is being built on Docker. I'm now looking for a simple way to deploy those containers to my Digital Ocean droplets (or AWS instances). I know you can use Docker Cloud for that, but that feels complicated (and it's limited to 1 Node).

I'm now manually deploying my containers on my servers (using pull and run). That works fine, but isn't there something I could use to automate this process? Preferable some service I run locally from the command line (not some cloud service) like pm2 for Node.JS applications.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest docker-machine + Docker swarm. 
Docker-machine would allow you provision from different providers, virtual box, AWs ...

Docker-Swarm would give you extendability.i.e. Where the containers are scheduled depends only on how you created the nodes. And, You keep the Swarm manager locally.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know docker-swarm yet!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for: docker-machine. As usual it's much simpler than I thought and it's included in Docker.

This tutorial describes the process of setting up and deploying to a VPS (in this case Digital Ocean): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-provision-and-manage-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-machine-on-ubuntu-16-04